# Shader that renders transparent instead of a color

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm totally new to shaders, I never made one

I was wondering if it's possibile to have a shader that renders an unlit texture normally except a specific color, which should be rendered as transparent

kinda like a greenscreen thing and i want to make the shader to render rgba(0,0,0,0) instead of rgba(0,1,0,1)

I know i could just use a texture with alpha, but i need this for a videotexture on mobile, so i thought this was the only option

Thank you in advance for any hint or answer provided

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a chroma key shader.

There are some details in [this Unity forum thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/chroma-key-shader.48938/) and I think this one will do what you're asking, although another solution might be "more better" depending on what you can do with your video source, etc. Give the thread a read if you can.

```
Shader "Matte/RGB Color"
{

Properties {
   _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
   _Matte ("Matte Color", Color) = (1,0,1,1)
   _Thresh ("Threshold", Range (0,1)) = 0.0
   _Cutoff ("Cutoff", Range (0,1)) = .5
}

SubShader {

   Pass {
      AlphaTest Less [_Cutoff]
CGPROGRAM
#pragma fragment frag
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

struct v2f {
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

sampler2D _MainTex;
uniform half4 _Matte;
uniform float _Thresh;
uniform float _Cutoff;

half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
{
    //return _Matte;
    half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv.xy);

    half3 keyMinus = half3( (_Matte.r - _Thresh), (_Matte.g - _Thresh), (_Matte.b - _Thresh) );
    half3 keyPlus = half3( (_Matte.r + _Thresh), (_Matte.g + _Thresh), (_Matte.b + _Thresh) );

    if ( ((color.r > keyMinus.r)  (color.r < keyPlus.r))  ((color.g > keyMinus.g)  (color.g < keyPlus.g))  ((color.b > keyMinus.b)  (color.b < keyPlus.b)) )
    {
        return _Cutoff;
    }

    return float4(color.rgb, max(0, _Cutoff-0.01));
}

ENDCG
      } // pass
   } // subshader
   //Fallback "Transparent/Diffuse"
} // shader
```

There are also assets on the asset store, such as [this one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/60917) ($8) which may work better or which may not.

Comment: Thank you for the hint!
Found a lot of good stuff there, but still not a shader that works properly.
At least I got to understand something about how shaders work